# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm new to coding in general so expect nooby behaviour.
i try to make discord music bot and it cant join voice chat and when i type node .an error pops up
i dont know where put import, i tried everywhere but i doesnt work, ping and youtube command work only play doesnt

This is the main code:

```js
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Musicbot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'ping'){
  client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
} else if (command == 'youtube'){
    client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
}  else if (command == 'play'){
    client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
}  else if (command == 'leave'){
    client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
} 


});







client.login('token');
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

This is the play command code:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    async execute(message, args){
   
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Musisz być na kanale głosowym by użyć tej komendy!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('Nie masz odpowiednich uprawnień');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('Nie masz odpowiednich uprawnień');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

        import { joinVoiceChannel } from "@discordjs/voice";
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel(
        {
        channelId: message.member.voice.channel,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });
        
     
    
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }

        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

        if(video){
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1});
            on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });

            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        }else {
            message.channel.send('Nie znaleziono wideo'); 
        }


    }
}
```

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `import { joinVoiceChannel } from "@discordjs/voice";` with `const { joinVoiceChannel } = require("@discordjs/voice");`.

This error occurred because you tried using [es modules import](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers) inside commonjs. You can however use [dynamic import](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions)s on commonjs if needed.